# InvalidArgumentError in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I`m trying to create neural network using Tensorflow tools.

```
sizeOfRow = len(data[0])
x = tensorFlow.placeholder("float", shape=[None, sizeOfRow])
y = tensorFlow.placeholder("float")

def neuralNetworkTrain(x):
  prediction = neuralNetworkModel(x)
  # using softmax function, normalize values to range(0,1)
  cost = tensorFlow.reduce_mean(tensorFlow.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(prediction, y))
```

this is a part from the net
I have got error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): logits and labels must be same size: logits_size=[500,2] labels_size=[1,500]
 [[Node: SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits = SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Reshape, Reshape_1)]]
```

someone know what`s wrong?

edit:
also I have got from this code:

```
for temp in range(int(len(data) / batchSize)):
    ex, ey = takeNextBatch(i) # takes 500 examples
    i += 1
    # TO-DO : fix bug here
    temp, cos = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict= {x:ex, y:ey})
```

this error 
   TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the error is quite self-describing.

`logits and labels must be same size: logits_size=[500,2] labels_size=[1,500]`

So, first, your labels should be transposed to have size `500, 1` and second, the [softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/nn.html#softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits) expects `labels` to be presented in a form of a probability distribution (e.g. `[[0.1, 0.9], [1.0, 0.0]]`).

If you know your classes are exclusive (which is probably the case), you should switch to using [sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/nn.html#sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits).